# Exclude an alias from virtualhost proxypass

Tags: linux, apache, ubuntu, odoo, virtualhost

I've following virtual host configuration. The desired result is:

1. If someone requests http://test.myserver.com/myapp, apache serves
   him from /var/www/myapp
2. And if http://test.myserver.com/ is
   requested, apache redirects it to port 8069.

2nd is working but 1st is not. Can someone help please!

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.myserver.com

        Alias /myapp /var/www/myapp
        <Directory /var/www/myapp>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8069/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/

</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is how I was able to achive the desired outcome. Following is the working configuration where `ProxyPassMatch ^/myapp !` did the trick and except the (server-address)/myapp, all the requests are being proxying to the other server which is open-erp running at port 8069:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName test.myserver.com

        Alias /myapp /var/www/myapp
        <Directory /var/www/myapp>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

        ProxyPassMatch ^/myapp !
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:8069/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8069/


  CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log common
  ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Very useful in combination with let's encrypt verification of virtual hosts that use reverse proxying, but still want to use automatic verify, e. g. Alias /.well-known "C:/apache24/htdocs/.well-known" 
 <Directory "C:/apache24/htdocs/.well-known">
   ...
 </Directory>

Comment: @AndiB The problem is that <Directory> can't use ProxyPass. Only <Location> and that doesn't work with Alias. Looking for a solution…

Comment: Here's a more thorough config recommendation: https://github.com/certbot/certbot/issues/2164 – The key is to use `ProxyPass /path /url` and not `<Location /path> ProxyPass /url` as I did before. Now it works for me.

Comment: @ygoe you're my hero today.

Answer (score 22):

Instead of using:`ProxyPassMatch ^/myapp !` you could have simply added another ProxyPass directive before the one defining /, like this:

```
ProxyPass /myapp !
ProxyPass / http://localhost:8069/
```

Since ProxyPass respects precedence (the first match will be processed), it will correctly redirect to the directory instead of proxying.

Comment: Make sure `http://localhost:8069/` server don't have any route named `/myapp` in the application. In my case it was showing `404`.

Comment: Hi will this make the final url look like `xyz.com/myapp`

Answer (score 1):

in case you have a **RewriteCond** (which is very likely when you run a proxy) this one will make you happy as well!

```
<Location /.well-known/acme-challenge/>
  RewriteEngine off
  ProxyPass !
</Location>
```