# how the alias proxypass priority works?

Tags: apache2, proxypass, mod-alias

I have a server with a proxy pass:

```
ProxyPass /service/ http://192.168.0.12/
ProxyPassReverse /service/ http://192.168.0.12/
ProxyRemote http://192.168.0.12/ http://myproxy.com:8123
```

however, for performance, I want to start serving the images directly fron the main machine with:

```
Alias /service/IMG2/ /var/www/Images/
```

But, it seems the proxy is always executed without taking into account the Alias. Is there a way to indicate apache to use the Alias before the proxypass?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is here:
[Exclude an alias from virtualhost proxypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848945/exclude-an-alias-from-virtualhost-proxypass)

In short, just add this line in front of your first `ProxyPath`:

> `ProxyPass /service/IMG2/ !`

Hope this helps.