# How to configure Apache ProxyPass and ProxyReverse for dotnet C# MVC routing in order to get exception for .well-known

Tags: asp.net, regex, apache, apache2, reverse-proxy

I've a site in `ASP.NET MVC Core 3.1 C#` running over a `Debian` with `Apache 2` trought a `ProxyPass` and `ProxyReverse` and a functional domain and SSL Let's Encrypt certificate with the following configuration in a `site-com.conf` file:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass / https://localhost:1234/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:1234/
ProxyPassMatch ^/.well-known !
```

So far so good, this works fine. But every time I need to update my certificates and I have to change the configuration to `<Directory>` in order the certbot can find the `.well-know` directory. This is not a problem but the site for this lapse is offline and I can't automate the process.

So I researched in `Server Fault` and `Stack Overflow` several solutions, nothing works. The more close solution is on this: [Exclude an alias from virtualhost proxypass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26848945/exclude-an-alias-from-virtualhost-proxypass)

But I can't manage to made it work. Last attempt with this configuration:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyPass / https://localhost:1234/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:1234/
 ProxyPassMatch ^/.well-known !



Alias /.well-known "/www/example.com/public_html/.well-known" 
<Directory "/www/example.com/public_html/.well-known" > 
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
 </Directory>
```

The url `example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/file` is catched by the `MVC Routing.`
I also created a `index.html` file to check the URL `example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/index.html` but happens the same.

**How can I configure this?**

I'm testing the RegEx now meanwhile we talk, but IDK where to begin to fix this.
Yes, I restart and reload the server everytime I do a change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally success. There were two problems: 1) It works better with `ProxyPass precedence` AND the `Allow` was not correct.

For this configuration it works:

```
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPass /.well-known !
ProxyPass / https://localhost:1234/
ProxyPassReverse / https://localhost:1234/


Alias /.well-known "/example.com/public_html/.well-known" 
<Directory "/example.com/public_html/.well-known" > 
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride All
Require all granted
 </Directory>
```